# I cannot get the String split method to work properly

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a String from an array into multiple Strings, before and after the "^". I used the String split method, but it is just storing the whole String in the first value of the array.

Output: b[0]= x^2
Expected: b[0] = x ,  b[1] = 2

Here is the code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        String a[] = {"x^2"};
        String b[] = a[0].split("^");

        System.out.println(b[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caret `^` is a special character in a *regular expression* meaning beginning of the `String`, escape it with `\`. Like,

```
String a[] = {"x^2"};
String b[] = a[0].split("\\^");

System.out.println(b[0]);
```